# Which access method is faster for Sql server

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ado.net

Is is better to use Ip in the sql server connection string or name? Which of these two will be faster?

Comment: you'd have to have a pretty bogged done dns server for the lookup of the name to be noticable plus your DNS Cache will hang onto it after the first lookup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, all things being equal,

- Hard-coded IP addresses: Bad
- Host names: Good.

Performance difference?  Negligible.

IMHO...